# Remotely access postgresql database with FDW [solved]

Tags: postgresql, remote-access

I have two servers hosted at different locations, with Postgresql.

I want to access to Postgresql data from server 1 (CentOS 7), by postgresql FDW from server 2 (Ubuntu 16).

The problem is :

`psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running         on host "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

I edited both postgresql.conf file with `listenaddresses='*'`  and both  pghba.conf file with `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`

still not work, so I thought it might be caused by iptables. I add these rules:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT`

Still not work.
Need advice.

Thanks you !

(sorry for my english)

Answer (score 0):

From the point of view of the network, server 2 is the client and server 1 is the server. The operating system of the client reports **Connection refused** when attempting to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432.

Generally that error is not due to a firewall, because firewalls tend to drop packets, which produce **Connection timed out**.

It's also not due to a postgres host-based authentication failure, as they produce completely different and specific error messages.

A few plausible reasons:

- PostgreSQL is indeed not listening on port 5432 on server 1. This can be confirmed with `netstat -tlnp | grep 5432` run as root. Note that the configuration parameter is `listen_addresses`, not `listenaddresses`.
  Also postgres need to be restarted after that change. You may look at the postgres server logs to confirm that it worked or check for the reason why it doesn't.
- The network configuration is such that server 1 cannot be reached from server 2 with the `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` address.  The packets are routed somewhere else, on a network interface where 5432 as a TCP port is not bound to a service. For instance if server 1 is virtualized, it is expected that it cannot be reached directly through the address of its host.

Comment: PostgreSQL listens on port 5432, it works, and of course has been restarted. (Yes, I meant `listen_adresses` and not `listenadresses`. Oops ...)

Obviously, the server 2 is a client from the point of view of the network. Thank you ! All that was needed : to allow the client to connect to the server. I added a rule to iptables and it works:

`-A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT`

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: @Splendens: good to hear that it's solved, but that iptable rule looks like it should not change anything compared to the `INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT` mentioned in the question.

Comment: Actually, I added this rule (`INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT`) on the server 2, first in order to connect remotely with pgadmin, and I forgot to add rules for the server 1. Your  answer made me realize my obvious omission.